# datatable how to get complete table from AJAX, without HTML

Tags: javascript, datatable

i am reading and reading, but not able to figure out this.

in my html i just have a placeholder:

```
<span ID="mytable"></span>
```

and I wish to populate it with a table pulled from backend using AJAX and drawn with Datatables.

```
//### get table drawn
function fetchTable(t){
  console.log('enter fetchTable fn, table: '+t);
  $.getJSON( "tabelmgr_ajax.pl?fetchTable="+t, function( data ) {
    var dataSet = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      dataSet.push(val);
      });

    console.log('dataSet='+dataSet);

    oTable = $('#'+t).DataTable({
      data: dataSet,
      bJQueryUI: true,
      sDom: '<"H"ilpt>',  // '<"H"lip>t<>'   or '<"H"lip>t' "dom": '<"top"iflp>', //show evrythin on top bar
    });

    oTable.draw().columns().every( function () {
      var that = this;
      $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
          that.search( this.value ).draw();
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

I simply want to load the complete table, nothing fancy. But I do not see any example on their website.

Comment: There are a lot of excellent examples on their web site.  The issue is probably in your Perl code.  Use the browser or web tools to verify the JSON returned is valid.

Comment: sorry but can you show me one example where they show column headers and rows are get from server as JSON data? ty.

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html - Note that in the HTML the columns are set up in an empty table.